# Cambiar estilo de campo vacío

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una practica y un apartado en cuestión me pide:

> Cuándo se empiece a escribir dentro de un input amarillo quitar el marcado amarillo de este.

Tengo el siguiente código en JavaScript el cual valida un formulario al hacer click en el botón, y marco en amarillo los recuadros que están vacíos. Ahora bien, intento hacer que cuando pincho en el input que está en amarillo se quede del color original.

```
function click1(){

    nombreApellidos= document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    direccion = document.getElementById('direccion').value;

    if (nombreApellidos == "" && direccion != ""){
        alert("Por favor, rellene su nombre y apellidos")
        document.getElementById('nombre').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

    } else if (nombreApellidos != "" && direccion == "") {
        alert("Por favor, rellene su dirección")
        document.getElementById('direccion').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

    } else if (nombreApellidos == "" && direccion == ""){
        alert("Por favor, rellene los campos vacios")
        document.getElementById('nombre').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";     
        document.getElementById('direccion').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

    } else {
        alert("Gracias! Todos los campos se han rellenado correctamente")
    }

}
```

He intentado a crear la siguiente función para eliminar el color amarillo cuando hago click en el input pero no ejecuta nada:

```
form = document.getElementById('formulario');
form.addEventListener("focus", eliminarCSS, true);

function eliminarCSS() {
    $('input[type="text"]').style.backgroundColor = "";  
}
```

No he logrado hacer que el color desaparezca, sigue en amarillo. Sé que debe ser una tontería pero no logro dar con la solución y me da mucho coraje no poder encontrarla, si me pueden echar una mano o explicarme a través de que método o función utilizar, se lo agradecería mucho.

Actualizo el HTML utilizado en la practica es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UF2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BS4/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tienda.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>UF2</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <form id='formulario'>
                <label>Nombre y apellidos</label>
                <input type='text' id='nombre'><br>
                <label>Dirección</label>
                <input type='text' id='direccion'><br>
                <label>Cantidad</label>
                <input type='number' id='cantidad' value='1' min='1'><br>
                <label>Seleccione talla:</label>
                XS<input type='radio' name='talla' checked value='XS'>
                S<input type='radio' name='talla' value='S'>
                M<input type='radio' name='talla' value='M'>
                L<input type='radio' name='talla' value='L'>
                XL<input type='radio' name='talla' value='XL'><br>
                <label>Seleccione color:</label>
                <select id='color'>
                    <option selected>blanca</option>
                    <option>amarilla</option>
                    <option>naranja</option>
                    <option>roja</option>
                    <option>verde</option>
                    <option>azul</option>
                    <option>negra</option>
                </select><br>
                <input type='button' id='enviar' value='Enviar' onclick= "click1()" ><br>
                <div id='resumen'></div>
            </form>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <img id='camiseta' src='img/camiseta_blanca.png'>
        </aside>
    </main> 



    <script src="BS4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="funciones.js"></script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Tiene que ser por javascript (creo que por css puro puede salir)?. Lo otro que veo es que tienes un mix entre "pure js" (js sin jquery) y Jquery. Iba a comenzar a armarte un ejemplo... pero no se si tu "ejercicio" tiene alguna restricción. Sería bueno que editaras tu pregunta ([edit]) y colocaras algo más de código (el html por ejemplo) para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Te recomendaría crear clases en CSS con los diferentes estilos y sólo cambiar la clase. Va a hacer tu código JS mucho más limpio y fácil de mantener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dado que no veo mayor necesidad de usar *JQuery* propongo la siguiente solución en JS

- Agrego a tres variables tanto los dos *inputs* como el botón que se encargará del envío del formulario
- Mediante el evento `click` verifico si las cajas de texto están vacías, si alguna de las 2 no tienen contenido entonces les coloco el color amarillo de fondo
- Opcionalmente en cada caso si las cajas de texto están vacías le coloco el `focus` a cada una
- Siguiente creo una función que va a verificar el evento `keyup` de cada caja de texto, para que a medida que se escriba texto en cada una de las cajas entonces cambiemos el color de fondo de las 2
- Al final invoco la función recién creada

Ejemplo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" id="name" />
      <br><br>
      <input type="email" id="email" />
      <button id="envia">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        let name = document.getElementById("name")
        let email = document.getElementById("email")
        let boton = document.getElementById("envia")
        
        boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          if(name.value === "") {
            name.style.background = "yellow"
            name.focus()
          }
          if(email.value === "") {
            email.style.background = "yellow"
            email.focus()
          }
        })
        
        function textoCajas() {
          name.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
              name.style.background = "white"
          })
          
          email.addEventListener("keyup",() => {
            email.style.background = "white"
          })
        }
      
        textoCajas()
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Me parece que podemos hacer mas legible el código que contiene la función realizando lo siguiente:

- Meter las variables que representan a cada `input` dentro de un vector
- con un `forEach` iterar el vector
- La variable `element` que representa a cada elemento del vector le agregamos un `listener`sobre el evento `keyup`
- A esa misma variable `element` le cambiamos el color

Entonces tan solo esa parte del script pudiera quedar así:

```
function textoCajas() {
          [name, email].forEach((element) => {
            element.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
              element.style.background = "white"
            })
          })
        }
```

> Con lo anterior estariamos logrando evitar código duplicado

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Ha sido actualizar el codigo con tu script y funcionar a la primera y creo que hasta el codigo es mucho mas sencillo de lo que yo me había complicado la vida.

Answer (score 3):

Asumiendo que no tienes restricción para utilizar `Jquery`, creo que te puedes valer de `focusin`  y `focusout` para hacer que te funcione. También utilicé  `addClass` y `removeClass` Te pongo el ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){  
  $('#formulario input[type="text"]').focusin(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('color');
  });
  $('#formulario input[type="text"]').focusout(function(){      
  if($(this).val() == ""){
   $(this).addClass('color');
  }
  });
});
```

```css
.color{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <form id="formulario">
    <input type="text" class="color" />
    <input type="text" class="color" />
    <input type="text" class="color" />
  </form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas Camilo, antes de todo darte las gracias por ayudarme. Estoy siguiendo tus recomendaciones, he añadido la clase .color al css y añadido la funcion al js  pero sigue sin eliminar el color amarillo.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca el nuevo código que estás utilizando para ver cómo podemos ayudarte.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta y colocado el HTML